# MSBuild: Colored cucumber output

Tags: windows, msbuild, cucumber

When I run cucumber from the windows command line I get colored output (currently using ANSICON).

When I use the following MSBuild target, run from the command line, I don't get colored output

```
<Target Name="Tests_Functional_Run">
    <Exec Command="bundle exec cucumber" />
</Target>
```

Any ideas how I can get colored output in MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I just had to read this question to see what "Colored Cucumber" was...

Are you building the project in Visual Studio, or using MSBuild from a command line? I ask because MSBuild from a command line puts out all sorts of coloured output, but I've never seen colour in the VS output window.

Answer (score 0):

The coloration is an artifact of the "display module" (for lack of a better term at hand).  The Windows console is sensitive to the type of message it displays from command-line output.

You'd need to make or find a VS add-in to colorize the Output pane.  Or copy the text into a capable editor and use its colorizing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal needs to support ANSI color. We use something called ANSICon here, it can be set up so it installs itself in all cmd shells and gives color output for cucumber.

Comment: Already using ANSICON (answers modified). I only lose color when I run the command in MSBuild.